# What are parenthesis infront of an iterator variable in Java?

Tags: java, syntax

```
    for (Iterator i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
    {
        Guitar guitar = (Guitar)i.next();
        if (guitar.getSerialNumber().equals(serialNumber))
        {
            return guitar;
        }
    }
```

I cant understand what **`(Guitar)i.next()`** is doing. It looks as if `Guitar` was passed to a function `(...)` but I'm guessing and have no clue. Also not easy to formulate a search query for this kind of construct so please excuse possible duplicate question.

Comment: you are using raw Iterator. that return Object when `next()` is called. Instead use generic Iterator where you don't need to downcast it.

Answer (score 2):

It's a casting statement. The reason is that `i.next()` returns an `Object`, but you know it is going to be a `Guitar`, so you tell the compiler:

> "Hey, compiler, I know it's going to be a `Guitar`, trust me."

The neat way of doing this would be to use generics. You're basically doing the same, but it's cleaner:

```
for (Iterator<Guitar> i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
{
     Guitar guitar = i.next();
     //...
}
```

Comment: I think `while` loop is more easy to understand it instead of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

`(Guitar)i.next();` is a *cast operator*. It is necessary here, because `i.next()` returns `java.lang.Object`, but you know it's a `Guitar`, and you want to use `Guiter`'s properties.

Note that the cast would become unnecessary if `guitars` is a generic collection, in which case the iterator can be properly typed:

```
List<Guitar> guitars = ...
for (Iterator<Guitar> i = guitars.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Guitar guitar = i.next(); // <<== The cast is no longer necessary
    if (guitar.getSerialNumber().equals(serialNumber))
    {
        return guitar;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think `while` loop is more easy to understand it instead of `for` loop.

Comment: The *explicit* cast is no longer necessary :) The cast is still done, but in the `next()` method.

Comment: @Braj `for`-loop was used in the question as well.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux That's right, Java generics are very much a "hide that cast from me" game.

Answer (score 0):

```
(Guitar)i.next();
```

is a cast to an object of class `Guitar` because `i.next()` returns in a raw `Iterator` an `Object` but the compiler needs to know that you have a `Guitar`-obejct in use to use the `Guitar`-class specific methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast i.next(), as others have said. I think `guitars` is a list, so you can also use a FOR EACH loop to iterate through it:

```
    for (Guitar guitar : guitars) {
        if (guitar.getSerialNumber().equals(serialNumber))
        {
            return guitar;
        }
    }
```